# Xcode retaincount = 1 inside dealloc

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wonder why the retaincount of an object equal one inside its dealloc function .

```
-(void) dealloc 
{
   NSlog(@"retain count = %i ", [self retaincount]);
   [super dealloc];
}
```

retain count = 1  so how the object called its dealloc function although its retain count equal 1 . As I know the object calls this function when its retain count is equal zero only .

Comment: is this means that the object is still live ?????

Comment: never count on retainCount http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636146/when-to-use-retaincount

Comment: I agree, don't use retain count as all of your other answers posted. But what happens if you call `[super dealloc]` first

Comment: if I call [super dealloc]; first , the object will be removed from memory so I will not be able to use self . But what will make me crazy is hoooooooow the object called its dealloc although its retain count equal 1 .

Comment: But as Mr. vikingosegundo and Mr.jbat100 told me not to use retaincount to debug .

Comment: See my answer; retainCount can never be zero because there would be no point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the retain count of an object can never be zero.

Decrementing it to zero is a waste of cycles because the object will b deallocated anyway.  retainCount can *never* return 0.

And:

## retainCount is useless.  Do not call it.

> Thank you .But how I can debug the existence of an object ??

Several ways;

- NSLog() in the -dealloc
- breakpoint on dealloc, print something, continue
- use Zombies
- use Allocations instrument
- use [Heapshot analysis](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Comment: Thank you .But how I can debug the existence of an object ??

Answer (score 3):

You can consider the object to be still alive in the `dealloc` method before the `[super dealloc];` call. This allows you to call messages on `self` to do some cleaning up within the dealloc. This is why `[super dealloc];` should always be called last. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939323/objective-c-retain-counts-in-dealloc) goes into some detail about why you shouldn't give any importance to the retain count in dealloc (or for that matter, anywhere).